# What is the final way to import es lodash modules?

Tags: javascript, lodash, es6-modules

So, I know there are a lot of similar questions here, I read all, as well as several web articles. Still, I cannot find a solution. I simply want to import es modules from lodash. Currently using rollup via codekit app.

Simply doing one of the following, will always end up in an empty js file:

```
import each from 'lodash-es';
import { each } from 'lodash-es';
import each from 'lodash-es/forEach';
import each from 'node_modules/lodash-es';
```

They all will end with the empty (currently compiling in iife):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
})();
```

Why?

Comment: Are you using the function in your code somehow? If not, then it probably gets stripped away due to tree shaking.

Comment: aaaa ok!!! That's true! Thank you!

Comment: if you want, add your answer, so I can check it as accepted

Comment: Sure, will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the function isn't used in the code in any way, it will get stripped from the production output due to a process called **tree shaking**. It's an optimization that looks at code imports and then eliminates any unused code as a result.

It turns out that was the case here as `each` wasn't used and it was imported only.

Comment: and say I would like to import several modules in one single file (ex. dependencies.js), without tree shaking, because I want to load it before any other script in evry page. Like a 'shared' library collection. Will the scripts in dependencies.js available (visible) for other scripts imported in other files (included in page after dependencies.js). It seems not, but can't understand why. I come from 'old school'... :P

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe it's good to set up a separate question with more information about usage. I can see several ways how to tackle that depending on the consumption pattern.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70853669/what-if-i-want-to-make-a-js-file-a-shared-library-of-es-modules/70853720?noredirect=1 :)