# What if I want to make a shared library out of ES modules?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

from some test I just did, it seems that if I import some modules in a say, dependencies.js file, without tree shaking, and then load it in page, and after it load another js file in page, that wants to use modules from dependencies.js, it won't work because it seems modules scoped to dependencies.js and not available outside.
Is it correct? And if I want, is there a way to 'solve' this problem?

Comment: Code is worth 1024 words. :-) Please **show** us what you did in `dependencies.js`, and what you tried to do afterward that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, adding my own answer here. So, to resume:

- Needed a way to load a shared.js file on all website pages, with all the shared libraries inside (things like Swiper, Fancybox, etc, which you want to be in cache and do not want to reload separetely or bundled on each page).
- Needed those libraries to be available to other js files and modules that are loaded in page after shared.js
- Needed to use es modules
- Needed to use bundlers (rollup in my case, or webpack)

**Problem # 1**

Modules scope is only the js files where they're defined or imported.

**Problem # 2**

By exporting modules and importing them in other module files:

- if we do not use bundlers, there will be performance issues (in other words, even if es modules are currently supported by all major browsers, it's not really recommended to use them raw > instead, we still need budlers > there are articles about this on the web).
- if we use bundlers, when importing libraries they will be added to the main file. Therefore, in this case, we would end up loading a copy of Swiper & co on each page.

**Solution #1 (the fast and dirty)**

In one sentence: on shared.js, import the modules and then add them to the global scope, the old school way: `window.Swiper = Swiper`.

Or, if you're really afraid of global variables (which have been used for 20 years now all over the web without destroying it, luckily...), on `shared.js` just export them, and by budling the file, you'll end up with the libraries on a sort 'namespaced' global scope. The budler will create one single variable (just look at the source of the budled file), which will serve as the access to the libs. Something like `shared.Swiper`. Whish just means `window.shared.Swiper`

**Solution #2 (the 'modern' one)**

Code splitting. All the main bundlers can do it in various ways, so just check docs from Webpack, Parcel, Rollup or Laravel mix.

Comment: "*if we use bundlers, when importing libraries they will be added to the main file.*" - no. You can declare some modules to be shared libraries, so they will be referenced instead of added to each build. For projects with multiple entrypoints, this can even be done automatically. Check the documentation of your bundler.

Comment: @Bergi, great, I didn't know, and that's the answer I needed. Could you maybe add it with some examples?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you re-export them from `dependencies.js`. For instance:

```
// dependencies.js
export { something } from "./something.js";
export { somethingElse } from "./something-else.js";
```

Note that they will *only* be re-exported, they won't be available to code in `dependencies.js`. If you want to use `something` / `somethingElse` in `dependencies.js`, import them, then re-export them:

```
// dependencies.js
import { something } from "./something.js";
import { somethingElse } from "./something-else.js";

export { something, somethingElse }; // Or export them individually
```

Either way, those exports will be available to anything consuming them from `dependencies.js`. But note that they'll also be available directly from `something.js` and `something-else.js`. (And either way, they're all bindings to the *same* exports.)

Comment: FWIW, I go into modules (including re-exporting) in detail in Chapter 13 of my recent book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: Great. And they won't be bundled together with the js files importing them. But this is going to work only if we use native ES modules, correct? And currently, If I correctly understand, the only browser that don't understand es modules, is IE, right?

Comment: P.s. congratulations for the book! :) I'd like to see / can buy it in pdf format!

Comment: @LucaReghellin - Right, only IE doesn't handle modules, but this also works if you use a good bundler. Yes, the book is available as a PDF from [the publisher](https://www.wiley.com/en-gb/JavaScript:+The+New+Toys-p-9781119367963). :-)

Comment: By using a bundler I guess code would be repeated/copied in all files where it's imported, right? (I used sort of a budler to create the dependencies file)